# Where to store plain text (magic strings) in Angular

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture, magic-numbers

In my Angular application I want to set simple error/notification messages in my controller. An example of this uses the [Material Snackbar for Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview):

```
this.snackBar.open(
  'Order successful',
  'OK',
  { duration: 2500 }
);
```

My problem is now, that I don't like to have 'magic strings' for my messages in my controllers.
Is there a best practice of storing this messages?

I thought about using 2.4 TypeScript enums with associated values in a dedicated error-message-model.

Experiences and suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for storing all your strings.

Then you can inject the service in your controller and use it to get strings like this:

```
translate.get('HELLO').subscribe((res: string) => {
  console.log(res);
  //=> 'hello world'
});
```

Or you can directly use it in template like this:

```
<div>{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}</div>
```

You can also have multiple languages support using this and it provides methods to listen for changes like `language change`.